# Virtualization for reasonable video performance

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I have recently built a new machine which I intend to use for gaming more than anything. To help keep the machine as clean as possible, I want to have a virtual machine running off a USB3 hard drive that I can use for  running Visual Studio, possibly photoshop and a few other bits.

My physical machine is running Windows 8 Pro and I've been experimenting with running a Windows 7 virtual machine through Hyper-V and while it works, the video performance is lacking. I'm not after anything amazing, but I do want to be able to watch the odd youtube video without having to constantly switch between the virtual and physical machines.

From what I have read, RemoteFX would help, but that doesn't appear to be an option when running anything but Server 2012 from the physical machine.

So it looks like I'll give Hyper-V the boot and will use another virtualisation technology instead. What should I be looking at to get OK video performance from my virtual machine?

Comment: What virtualization software do you use? If VMWare make sure accelerated 3D is enabled and VMWare tools is installed into the Guest OS.

Comment: I was just using the Hyper-V stuff that comes with Windows 8 Pro, but I've given that up and am now trying VMWare Player

Answer (score 1):

VMWare Player works a treat. Pretty reasonable video performance and free! So pretty happy about that!